# React useEffect hook disable additional renders while dispatching actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, use-effect

I am using useEffect hook in this way:

```
const AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL = 1000;
useEffect(() => {
    if (dataChanged()) {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            saveData();
        }, AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL);
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}, [dataChanged, saveData]);
```

The saveData redux action looks like this:

```
const saveData = (): ThunkResult => (dispatch) => {
    /* ... saving data code ... */
    dispatch(action1());
    dispatch(action2());
};
```

When useEffect is called first time, it will re-render the component.
But then after calling the saveData method, the useEffect hook is called additional 2 times.

First re-render is fine - it will save data, but additional two re-renders are useless because useEffect is called only based on dispatching these 2 actions.

My question is how can I disable re-render of the component while I am dispatching these 2 actions in the saveData redux action? Or where should I put these 2 actions so that the component will not re-render?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you disable React.strictmode?

Comment: can u share where dataChanged is changing?